# Postgres - Change values before returning result set from a view

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres view that returns records with either 'Y' or 'N' as the value, and I'd like to convert them to 'Yes' or 'No' before the final SQL results are returned. For instance:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW transit_info AS 
 SELECT 
 ('Train Service:'::text || tblpoi_transit_info.train_service::text AS train_service,
```

I'd like to convert train_service to a 'Yes' or 'No' depending on the recorded value. Any way to do this easily? I've been experimenting with CASE statements but haven't really got the syntax down yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ('Train Service:'::text
    ||
    case tblpoi_transit_info.train_service::text
        when 'Y' then 'Yes' else 'No'
    end AS train_service,
```